# The problem to get the % of all the attendance for each student

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My aim is to get the presentage of the students with other attributes too, based on present or absent. I have search everything but i dont know how to implement it in Laravel, Im confuse i dont know why.

I first tired to get the total count but nothing worked. please help me to get this done in laravel query builder. Thanks

```
DB::table('attendances')->
    select(
        'courses.name as course_name',
        'sections.name as section_name',
        'students.name as student_name',
        'students.rollnumber as student_rollnumber',
        'attendances.is_present as is_present',
        'attendances.date as date',
        DB::raw('COUNT(attendances.id) as tcount')
    )
    ->join('courses','courses.id','attendances.course_id')
    ->join('sections','sections.id','attendances.section_id')
    ->join('students','students.id','attendances.student_id')
    ->where('attendances.student_id',$id)
    ->where('attendances.course_id',$course_id)
    ->where('attendances.section_id',$section_id)
    ->groupBy('attendances.id')
    ->get();
```

My expect result, i will get all other info with a attribute names as percentile. Hint(I have an attribute in attendences table call is_presnet with value 0 or 1)

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using Eloquent and it's relationships for this? Can you explain how your feel the percentage should work as well i.e. is it a percentage of attendance for each student or is it an overall percentage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as I understand you need to get the % attendance of each student for the given course.

In your SQL query group by attendances.id is not needed since each attendance id is unique. If you remove following two lines:

```
DB::raw('COUNT(attendances.id) as tcount')
```

and

```
->groupBy('attendances.id')
```

It should return all the attendances of the student in the given course. You can loop over the result data using Php. Within the loop you can check how many present rows are present. If you divide the total number of presents by the total number of attendances, you will get the % attendance of the student for the given course

Comment: yes finaly this was the option i have...and i did.. Thanks for telling but i was looking for another way too. :)